# IOS how to let MPMediaPickerController to come out in landscape mode only?

Tags: ios, landscape-portrait

For some reasons I restrict my app to work only on landscape mode,  but strangely when I open iPod music library from my app, it will always jump out in portrait mode.

See the following code, I am confused whether it is system default behavior? How can I tell it to come out in landscape mode (keep consistent with other UI)?  Thanks.

```
- (IBAction)getMusic:(id)sender {
    MPMediaPickerController *picker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeMusic];
    picker.delegate                     = self;
    picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems   = YES;
    picker.prompt                       = NSLocalizedString (@"Add songs to play",nil);

    [self presentModalViewController: picker animated: NO];
    [picker release];
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);;
    } else {
        return YES;

    }
}
```

Comment: Seems be IOS default behavior, only jump out in portrait mode.

Comment: Updated my answer for iOS 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MPMediaPickerController Class reference:

> Notes: The MPMediaPickerController class supports portrait mode only.
>   This class does support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class
>   is private; do not modify the view hierarchy.

There are posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687388/mpmediapickercontroller-orientation-on-ipad) and [elsewhere](https://iphonedevsdk.vanillaforums.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/105699-mpmediapickercontroller-orientation.html) that describe workaround, but I can't vouch for them.

Comment: I should mention that if you push it onto a NavigationController, it will show up in landscape.  That is, you can get around the note in Apple's class reference.

Comment: Plz see the following my answer. Just add the view of MPMediaPickerController to the parent viewcontroller's view.

Comment: what's wrong with the answer all of a sudden, oh noble downvoter?

Answer (score 5):

Just add the view of MPMediaPickerController to a viewcontroller's view that supports orientations that you want.
(tested in iOS 6.1 SDK)

```
mediaPickerController = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeAny];

mediaPickerController.delegate = self;
mediaPickerController.allowsPickingMultipleItems = NO;
mediaPickerController.prompt = @"Select songs to edit";

//[self presentViewController:mediaPicker animated:YES completion:^{}];
[self.view addSubview:mediaPickerController.view];
```

[image]

In addition, in case of iOS 7 you should set media picker's frame as below.

```
mediaPickerController = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeAny];

mediaPickerController.delegate = self;
mediaPickerController.allowsPickingMultipleItems = NO;
mediaPickerController.prompt = @"Select a song to edit";

// in case of iOS 7
mediaPickerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 568, 320);

[self.view addSubview:mediaPickerController.view];
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Still actual for  IOS 13.